# Exception in WebMethod

Tags: c#, webmethod

My Question is regarding Web-services

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(bool Done)
    {


       return "";

    }
```

When i click the Invoke button, giving blank value we get an Exception, is there a way to handle this, and give an Informative message

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.Boolean.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest
```

I have even tried it as

```
public string HelloWorld(bool Done=false)
```

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean` what did you pass in?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention i prefer to have a default value as false if user don't pass any data

Comment: try this: public string HelloWorld(bool? Done)

Comment: You may be better off with a string parameter, and handling empty string/true/false/anything else